# Use meta boxes inside an archive page template for Woocommerce

Tags: metabox, templates, woocommerce-offtopic, template-hierarchy, archive-template

I'm creating my own Wordpress theme, and I'm trying to make it compatible with Woocommerce. I understand pretty much everything about theming woocommerce, including copying the template files and changing them, also I'm confortable with some of the Woocommerce hooks as well.

Now Woocommerce uses an archive-product.php file to show shop items, and it is also currently using the a page named 'Shop' for that. The problem is that I'm not able to use the custom meta box data in my archive-product.php file when I save them in the 'Shop' page.

So I just want to know if there is anyway of using meta box data in an archive template, such as the archive-product.php template of Woocommerce.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** So I was able to solve my problem completely by using the following code in the file that I'm including:

```
if( is_shop() ) {
  $post_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );;
} else {
  $post_id = $post->ID;
}

$meta_key = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', true);
```

Comment: It should be the same as in any other theme. _What have you tried?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce does hijack the main query on the shop page / product queries, so it's possible that you're used to referencing your custom fields within the loop or in some other context where the global $post is the page you are on, but in this case the contents of $post will be Woocommerce products and not the page.

If this is for your base shop page you can reference the custom fields like this (change for the meta_key of your custom meta box  fields)

```
//returns shop page post object
$your_shop_page = get_post( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );

//access your meta fields like this
$your_shop-page->your_meta_key;
```

I hope this helps in your situation, if you use the above code it would help to make sure you are on the shop page and those values exist before attempting to output them, always code defensively!

Comment: I agree that meta works the same... just need the right page ID.  I think `$page_id = get_queried_object_id();` ought to work too.

Comment: @helgatheviking correct, great way to get the original, though wouldn't returning the whole object via `get_queried_object` be more useful? as archive.php is used for shop and categories extra code would be needed to differentiate between the two, as when on an archive it will return a category (term) object which will likely not have these meta box fields (most people don't add meta to terms, though it sure can be useful)

Comment: Any post meta can be accessed through the post object via the WP_Post's magic methods. This is what the 2nd part of the code I posted is: if you are working with the a post object `$post_object->meta_box_key` is the same thing as `get_post_meta( id, 'meta_box_key', true)`.

Comment: Didn't know about the magic methods. Thanks for that bit of knowledge. +1

Comment: Full code would be `$current_page = get_queried_object(); $your_meta =$current_page->meta_box_key;`

Comment: For future reference, a meta-box is simply a container in the admin in which we can place input fields, which we then save to post meta. When accessing these properties we refer to them as post meta / custom post meta /custom fields, the meta box is just how we input them. Using correct terminology in the future makes it easier for people to help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what you showed worked. However, I have a file that handles all the page meta box options, that is included in page.php, page_blog.php and other page templates. And in this file I use get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', true). I was hoping to include the same file in archive-product.php but it was not working as I said. I'm confused about whether I should replace the code in this file with what you've showed, or create a different file just for Woocommerce pages, which will contain the same settings accept in the format that u should. Please help me with this as well. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, the issue is that archive pages automatically generated by wordpress do not have a post object, they are not a post unlike all the other pages. They are a term, and thus have a term object which is quite different to a post object and thus most of the methods/functions etc that you see for working with wordpress do not work. Search the codex for terms and term objects for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In the template that is being included, you might be able to do something like this:

```
global $post;
if( get_queried_object_id() == wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) {
  $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
} else {
  $post_id = $post->ID;
}

get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true);
```

So that it will work for either a blog post or the archives.

Untested, so your mileage may vary. ;)

Comment: Yes, I tried this but get_post_meta() just doesn't work in the archive-product.php file, even when I directly put the post_id in the get_post_meta() function, like this: get_post_meta(4, 'meta_key', true);

Comment: If you are hard-coding `get_post_meta( 4, 'meta_key', true );` and still get nothing, then you don't have a meta value for the `meta_key` for a post with an ID of 4. The function works everywhere regardless of template.